# Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'John'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a JSON:

```
json: string = `{
          "name" : "John",
          "surname" : "Walsh",
          "age" : "23"
    }`;
```

And I need to show it in table:

```html
<table width="700">
            <caption>All Users</caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>surname</th>
                    <th>age</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                 <tr>
                    <td *ngFor="let names of users"></td>
                       {{ names}}
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I tried to do like this:

```
users = JSON.parse(this.json);
```

but got an error:

> Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'John'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Then I tried convert users to array like this:

```
arr:Array<{key: string, value: string}> = [];
constructor(){
    for (var key in this.users) {
      if (this.users.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       this.arr.push({ key: key, value: this.users[key] });
      }
 }
}
```

but I can't iterate it using `NgFor`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first place, you need to correct array of your users to this:

```
users = [{
      "name" : "John",
      "surname" : "Walsh",
      "age" : "23"
},{
      "name" : "Mike",
      "surname" : "Mikic",
      "age" : "25"
}];
```

In the same time, you should iterate and create a new row each time you pass one object:

```
<table width="700">
    <caption>All Users</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>surname</th>
            <th>age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
            <td>
                  {{user.name}}
            </td>
            <td>
                  {{user.surname}}
            </td>
            <td>
                  {{user.age}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Really problem was with my JSON`s view.

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr *ngFor="let names of users">
    <td > {{ names.name}}</td>
    <td > {{ names.sername}}</td>
    <td > {{ names.age}}</td>          
</tr>
```